# Platform support in manifest file

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

Is it possible to specify Platform along with Hosts in manifest file ? Any workaround to show the addin only for Web client not for thick client?

something like ...
location.search ? or Platform or isSetSupported('ExcelApi',

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to limit your add-in to being installable only on a particular platform. You could try to use the [Office.context.diagnostics.platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/office/office.context?view=common-js#platform) property, so that on platforms that you don't want to support, the add-in's UI branches to a message saying that the add-in can only be used on Office on the web. But if you plan to distribute the add-in in AppSource, I don't know if it would be accepted because part of the point of Office add-ins is that they are cross-platform so that the choice of platform is up to the user, not the developer.

Answer (score 0):

The add-in validation team support this. While your submission is expected to work cross-platform, not all APIs may work the same way in different clients (may be buggy) and if you have a strong justification for not releasing in a certain platform, the add-in validation team *can* approve your app with a special permission. As a result of this, your add-in will be only visible to only the platforms that was specified by the validation team.

Please see the availability matrix here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability

That said, you will have to prove why you are omitting a platform. As Rick highlighted - these add-ins are meant to be cross-platform.